# Laravel blade section inheritance

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have file views/admin/header.blade.php, in which I have section

```
@section('header')
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/admin/faculties"></a></li>
    </ul>
@endsection
```

And file views/admin/faculties.blade.php, in which I am trying to display header, but it doesn`t work:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    @yield('admin.header')
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the word 'admin', only the actual name you gave to your section:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    @yield('header')
@endsection
```

Update after first comment of original poster:
You might need an `@include` statement instead of `@yield`.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    @include('admin.header')
@endsection
```

Your header blade will need to change to this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/admin/faculties"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I`ve tried to write like this, but got the same result